# ¿Como aumentar la velocidad a los comandos en Android?

Tags: java, android

**Hola a todos**

**Mi problema:** me encuentro en la situación de poder incrementar la velocidad a los comandos en los dispositivos android, porque me he adentrado a lo permisos Root y para ello debo utilizar el terminal de comandos como Root para realizar movimientos Root, uno de ello es el comando de copiado (cp), y ya que muevo archivos grandes de un lugar a otro me encuentro en la necesidad de tener que aumentar esa velocidad, no se si se pueda realizar por un comando que aumenta la velocidad de ejecución o procesamientos de los comandos o por otro comando que permita poner mi proceso en un puesto de los primeros en la lista de ejecución de android, o si existe alguna  otra forma desde código java o otras.

**Mi código:**

```
        public boolean copiar(){
        String[] command = {"su", "-c", "cp", "ruta del fichero", "ruta a copiar"};

            try {
                Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Si", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

    boolean verdadero = true;
    return true;

}
```

**El copiado se realiza de la sdcard y tarjeta SD con la particion system, data. etc, donde quiera ponerlo el usuario**

Si conocen algo referente estaré encantado de escucharlo. Gracias

Comment: Has intentado ponerle un procesador mas rápido? jaja, eso es un chiste. Pero si, si la copia se hace desde una Sd a la memoria interna( o viceversa), quizá la memoria externa sea de una clase baja. Las clases son 2, 4, 6 y 10 según [wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/SDHC)

Comment: He hecho una modificación a la pregunta, gracias por su comentario.

Comment: has intentado comandos de linux como en [este post](http://www.bencane.com/2013/09/09/setting-process-cpu-priority-with-nice-and-renice/) ?depues de todo es linux, mira esto tambien [comandos](http://www.all-things-android.com/content/android-toolbox-command-reference) Podrías ver si existe el comando nice-renice

Comment: Gracias por su aporte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te aconsejo utilizar [FileChannel](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) si el tamaño de los ficheros es grande.
Prueba con el siguiente código y compara tiempos de ejecución.

```
public void copy(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(src);
FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(dst);
FileChannel inChannel = inStream.getChannel();
FileChannel outChannel = outStream.getChannel();
inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
    inStream.close();
    outStream.close();
}
```

Comment: Este método es valido, pero me encuentro en una situación que necesito utilizar comandos. Gracias

Comment: En ese caso, y siempre y cuando tengas que copiar más de un fichero, quizás notes cierta mejora en los tiempos lanzándolos en background añadiendo "&" (sin comillas) al final del comando, permitiendo así la paralelización de las copias.

Comment: Pero también aumentaría la velocidad del proceso o solo paraliza los demás procesos de copiado  o paraliza todos los demás que no tienen mucha importancia. Gracias.

Comment: Añadir andpersand al final de un comando permitirá que dicho comando (y solo ese) sea ejecutado en segundo plano. Por lo tanto, añádelo donde creas que sea necesario.

Comment: Estoy realizándolo correctamente:  `su -c cp Ruta del fichero ruta a copiar &`

Comment: **¿Esto como mejora la velocidad del proceso?** si el OP esta preguntando mediante: Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command); La lentitud no se debe en este caso a el tamaño de los archivos si no a a la ejecución de un proceso que realiza la copia mediante Runtime.getRuntime().exec().